# how to make directory first and then upload image on that directory through multer in node js

Tags: node.js, multer

I want to upload image through multer but first i want to create a directory or folder for every user and then upload the image to that users folder.

If I create a folder for a user myself and upload, passing the `user_id`, the image is uploaded into that folder. 
But if I do it through code, I am not able to do that.

When  in destination I am adding `req.body.user_id` it gives me `undefined`.
like this :- 
     var storage = multer.diskStorage({

```
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, __dirname + '/images/'+ req.body.user_id)

        } 

[
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({

        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, __dirname + '/images/' )

        },

        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now())
            //console.log(file);

        }
    });

    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('image');

    var formatted = new Date().toLocaleString();



    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        var data = {
            "user_id": req.body.user_id,
            "item_id": req.body.item_id,
            "sell_type": req.body.sell_type,
            "sell_name": req.body.sell_name,
            "sell_location": req.body.sell_location,
            "sell_price": req.body.sell_price,
            "data_post": formatted
        };
              console.log("error ==>",err);
        if(err){
            res.status(400).json({
            "status_code": 'ERROR',
            "message": "image  uploadinf Fail"
            });

        }else{

            fs.exists("/var/www/html/Anoop/nodetest/images/" + data.user_id, (exists) => {
                console.log(exists);
                if(exists) {

                            res.status(200).json({
                                "status_code": "SUCCESS",
                                "message": "uploaded",
                                "data": req.file.path

                            });

                } 
                else 
                {   
                    mkdirp("/var/www/html/Anoop/nodetest/images/" + data.user_id, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.status(400).json({
                                "status_code": "ERROR",
                                "message": "dir not created"

                            });
                        } else {
                            //console.log(result);
                            res.status(200).json({
                                "status_code": "SUCCESS",
                                "message": "dir created",
                                "data": req.file.path

                            });

                        }
                    });

                }

            });


        }


    });

});

 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
const fs = require('fs')
const filesDir = 'files';

// check if directory exists
if (!fs.existsSync(filesDir)) {
// if not create directory
    fs.mkdirSync(filesDir);

}
```

Comment: Still not working :( Can u tell me how can i get the value of user_id in multer where we define destination . if i do req.body.user_id its output is UNDEFINED. Anything outside the upload function if i am doing it give me undefined.

*****************
 var storage = multer.diskStorage({

        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, __dirname + '/images/' req.body.user_id) <-- here i want user_id

        }